# Ajax BeginForm of list returns only first element of model or null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an action with an ajax-beginform.

This is my model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<SubViewModel> SubViewModels {get;set;}
}

public class SubViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public bool Active {get;set;}
}
```

My view looks like this: (I'm iterating over all SubViewModel-Items, and want to get those back later in my DoAction-Method)

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoAction", "MyController", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { @class = "search-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.SubViewModels)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="@item.Name" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Age" value="@item.Age" /></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Active" value="@item.Active" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        </table>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

And this is my action:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public async Task DoAction([FromBody] MyViewModel model)
{
    // here model is null
}
```

It always hits the breakpoint in `DoAction` but:

- if the type of model is `MyViewModel`, the property `SubViewModels` is null.
- if the type of model is `IEnumerable<SubViewModel>`, the model is null.
- if the type of model is `SubViewModel`, the first dataset is in parameter.

So I guess, the right parameter for this ajax-action is from type `SubViewModel`.

**But I need either `MyViewModel` or `IEnumerable<SubViewModel>` to get all listed models items.**

Comment: Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for an explanation and alternative using an `EditorTemplate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to name your inputs such that the modelbinder can bind the post data appropriately. As you have it now, every single item in the list is posted via the same property names: `Name`, `Age`, and `Active`. What you actually need are names like `SubViewModels[N].Name`, where `N` is an integer index value. The easiest way to do this to actually use the HTML helpers to generate your inputs, and you'll also need to use a `for` loop, rather than `foreach`:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SubViewModels.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubViewModels[i].Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubViewModels[i].Age)</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SubViewModels[i].Name)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: That finally worked. Great. I'd have been to lazy to try with for and index. :D Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Chris pratt : I did the same, but I still not getting values in list property